# Writing to read-only P3IN

Tags: c, contiki

I am trying to compute hash of IPv6 packet after header compression using [quark](https://www.131002.net/quark/). The hash is computed over compressed IPv6 header and payload.

[This](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/ipv6/sicslowpan.c#L1269) line mentions that the IP packet is initially in `uip_buf` and `uip_len` gives the length of the contents in `uip_buf`.

The prototype of quark is `int quark( u8 *out, const u8 *in, u64 inlen );`

I am calling `quark( out, uip_buf, uip_len );` [after IPv6 header compression](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/ipv6/sicslowpan.c#L1339). I compute hash only if the packet is large enough to be fragmented.

I am using z1 motes, cooja simulator in contiki 3.0.
I am getting the following issue :

```
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) - Writing to read-only P3IN
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) - 
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) - Stack Trace: number of calls: 13 PC: $07a36
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   permute_u (serial-line.c) called from PC: $07f76 (elapsed: 890)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   permute (local in sicslowpan.c) called from PC: $0806e (elapsed: 49789)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   update (serial-line.c) called from PC: $08150 (elapsed: 70287)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   quark (serial-line.c) called from PC: $0874e (elapsed: 127697)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   output (local in sicslowpan.c) called from PC: $0a288 (elapsed: 247738)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   tcpip_output (serial-line.c) called from PC: $0a3b8 (elapsed: 247750)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   tcpip_ipv6_output (serial-line.c) called from PC: $09ffa (elapsed: 247800)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   uip_icmp6_send (serial-line.c) called from PC: $0c066 (elapsed: 248724)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   dis_output (serial-line.c) called from PC: $0c79c (elapsed: 248786)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   handle_periodic_timer (local in rpl-timers.c) called from PC: $06496 (elapsed: 249098)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   process_thread_ctimer_process (local in ctimer.c) called from PC: $068aa (elapsed: 249237)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   call_process (local in process.c) called from PC: $06a28 (elapsed: 249272)
[java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageListUI.java:261) -   process_run (serial-line.c) called from PC: $033f2 (elapsed: 250282)
```

After some search I understood that possible reasons can be:

1. A function returns negative or large number.
2. Array index out of bounds.

I am sure about no such possibility in my code but I don't know if any possibility in [quark.c](https://github.com/veorq/Quark/blob/master/quark.c). I am just using rpl-udp client and server. I am sending only 134 bytes of data from client as data.

Just before the error pops up, Mote output displayed the values that I had printed from the code.
`uip_len = 116 sizeof(uip_buf) = 1280`

Any solution or hints to get rid of the error?